# A little confusion about calculating variance?

Tags: probability, statistics, multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations, covariance

given $a = 10% $, $b = 50%$, $c = 25%$ and $d = 15% $
calculate the variance? ( this is a made up question to make thinks clear for me)

what i have done is 1st eliminate percentages?
then i calculated the variance for $a = 0.1$, $b = 0.5$, $c = 0.25$, & $0.15$

But then I was wondering, do I need to multiply by the total before getting variance?
so, a would be $a = 10/100 * 4 = 0.4$, $b = 50/100 * 4 = 2$, ......
then calculate the variance.

Do I have to do it in percentages or completely un-normalized form?

Comment: Are those numbers probabilities or observed values or frequencies? What is $4$?

Comment: 4 islike total number of the letters. u remember to get percentage, its value/total * 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i left it in percentages